# Spaceship Generator - Error Message

Tags: python

Dear community members,

I am a newbie in Blender and I also cannot program software. Unfortunately, I get with the Spaceship Generator an error message. Please see attachment. Could someone please help?

I have the Atom editor, so in case, someone know a solution, I can do it in Atom editor. Thank you very much. Have a great day. Stay safe.

Martina[image: Screenshot of Spaceship Generator Error]

Comment: https://github.com/a1studmuffin/SpaceshipGenerator/issues/45

Comment: Thanks. The problem was, that the spaceship generator only works in Blender 2.8 and in 2.9.